# Query terminal colors via OSC11

Tags: neovim, terminal, colorscheme

Is it possible to query the terminal colors via OSC-11 used in highlight groups? Similar to what is done here https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/5d8ab32f3871b0232972cac1116ac7cba98389e5/src/nvim/tui/input.c#L602

I would like to query the colors and modify the gradient slightly in my color scheme because I manage my colors scheme through the terminal.